# Setting Focus on QPushButton on pressing Enter

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, setfocus

I have to set focus on a QPushButton upon clicking enter in a QLineEdit, and I am able to achieve the same but the problem is that the action to be performed on button click is also getting triggered. Although I am not clicking the button, only calling setFocus()
Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit, QDialog
import sys, time


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PushButton Set Focus'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit('Press Enter', self)
        self.lineEdit.move(100, 30)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.__setFocusOnButton)

        self.button = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        self.button.move(100, 70)
        self.button.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    def on_click(self):
        print('Button Clicked')

    def __setFocusOnButton(self):
        self.button.setFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please let me know if there are some methods to setFocus without clicking.

Comment: provide a [mre]. If the code does not reproduce the problem then it does not help to understand the problem. On the other hand, is the button in a QDialog?

Comment: Then modify your example using a QDialog and check if the problem is shown, if so then update your question with the new code.

Comment: The actual button is on a QDialog. Ill try to write a MRE with QDialog.

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button) points out:

> #### Default Button
>
> **A dialog's default button is the button that's pressed when the user
>   presses Enter (Return)**. This button is used to signify that the user
>   accepts the dialog's settings and wants to close the dialog. Use
>   QPushButton::setDefault(), QPushButton::isDefault() and
>   QPushButton::autoDefault() to set and control the dialog's default
>   button.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So there are 2 possible solutions:

- Do not use QDialog but QWidget, OR
- set the autoDefault property to false: `self.button.setAutoDefault(False)`